# Incorrect tag badge awarded

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-badges

I was just awarded the silver [c] badge [several minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/52/c?userid=718379). However, according to the description, it is awarded to users who earned at least 400 total score for at least 80 non-community wiki answers. But I earned only 306.

This looks like an error.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Did I get my gold tag badge incorrectly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254395/did-i-get-my-gold-tag-badge-incorrectly)

Comment: @Makoto That's `c++` tag, not `c`.

Comment: Sorry, that was me misreading the tag.  Something does seem a bit off here...

Comment: I got the c++ silver badge, but at least my official tag score is close (393). And I don't think the tag scores have updated in a couple of days, so it seems plausible that I indeed have 400. But it seems unlikely that you would have accumulated a score of 94 in a couple of days. Well, to be more precise, I got the notification in the progress on the Activity page. I do not have the actual badge yet.

Comment: @animuson Mabey the system counts total votes not total vote score for this so someone with a thousand downvotes might get a badge.

Comment: @jakekimds , this is definitely a bug as many such incidents have occurred today ( I've seen 5 posts on meta today related to this )

Comment: Same here, I was tracking CSS3 badge and it says I got the badge, but I've not reached 1k votes in CSS3 yet nor did I received any badges and I cannot track the badge anymore