# "next tag badge" feature thinks I earned a badge I didn't

Tags: bug, tag-badges

The "next tag badge" feature on my Activity tab just congratulated me on getting the silver Linux badge, which I have [definitely not earned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/165/linux?userid=1204143) - I have only 379 rep in that badge (out of 400 needed).

It's pretty convinced of this fact:

> [image: "Select your next badge" screen showing incorrect checkmark on Linux badge.]

Comment: Related [Incorrect tag badge awarded](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291546/incorrect-tag-badge-awarded)

Comment: Possibly related, but in that case that user actually received the badge. In my case, I have not received the badge but some other function thinks I did.

Comment: The system is still slowly awarding all these incorrect tag badges. You might actually receive it at some point if this doesn't get fixed quickly. :P

Comment: I just had the same thing happen to me with the Android tag badge and the "next tag badge" feature.  I just looked at the Android tag badge page, and there is definitely something wonky going on today: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/291/android

Comment: Cross-site dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254396/tracked-tag-badge-incorrectly-shown-as-earned. That one covers the case where the notification was shown, but the badge not (yet) awarded.