# Does this gold badge belong to me?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, badges, tag-badges

Torture. Painful one. Be forced to do this...

I was just informed, that I received a gold badge for [NHibernate tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1198/nhibernate?userid=1679310). *(Because of this question - I also added a picture to show that it **really did happen**)*

[image]

But this does not seem to be correct at all. Sadly.

> *Disclaimer: I (almost desperately) wish to have the honor of being among awarded with [NHibernate tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1198/nhibernate). Honestly, NHibernate (while awesome, tremendous, mighty... tool) is dying, if not already dead. Questions rate is almost zero. And I need 130 another up-votes...*

So, I do not meet the requirement. I do not have **at least 1000 total score**. I have [only 870](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679310/radim-k%C3%B6hler?tab=tags):

[image]

My question, or, what I am asking for: could you, please, fix it? *(did I say that?)* I do not deserve this ... yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incorrect tag badge awarded](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291546/incorrect-tag-badge-awarded)

Comment: @Roombatron5000, it's still a duplicate of [Tag badges are being awarded incorrectly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254395/tag-badges-are-being-awarded-incorrectly)

Comment: @jarrod - **FINALLY !!!** It couldn't have been a bug. System, was just a **visionary**. Now it shows that I do deserve that badge: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1198/nhibernate?userid=1679310 ;) ;) ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One should never push code right before going on vacation.

The bug has been fixed, a test has been written, and any incorrectly-awarded badges have been revoked.  Your topbar's achievement list has also been cleaned.

My apologies.

Comment: The badge might show on your profile for a bit due to caching.

Comment: So were you penalized some vacation time?